# Different answer using Dsolve or NDSolve to solve a PDE

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I'm working on getting a numerical solution for the following PDE:
$$
u_t-u_{xx}=0,\ x\in[0,1], t\in[0,1],\\
u(x,0)=\sin(2\pi x),\\
u(0,t)=0,\\
u_x(1,t)=2\pi e^{-t}.
$$
The hand solution for this PDE is $u(x,t)=e^{-t}\sin(2\pi x)$.

I tried `DSolve` to get the analytical solution.

```
DSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] - D[u[x, t], x, x] == 0, 
  u[x, 0] == Sin[2 \[Pi] x], u[0, t] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][u][1, t] == 2 \[Pi] E^-t}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

> $$\underset{K[1]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  x (2 K[1]-1)\right) \left(-\frac{32 (-1)^{K[1]} \left(-\cosh (t)+e^{-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 t (1-2 K[1])^2}+\sinh (t)\right) \sqrt{2}}{\pi  \left(4-\pi ^2 (1-2 K[1])^2\right) (1-2 K[1])^2}-\frac{128 (-1)^{K[1]} e^{-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 t (2 K[1]-1)^2} \sqrt{2}}{\pi  (1-2 K[1])^2 \left(4 K[1]^2-4 K[1]-15\right)}\right)+2 \pi  e^{-t} x$$

However, `DSolve` gives an answer containing `Inactive[Sum]`.

I also tried `NDSolve`:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] - D[u[x, t], x, x] == 0, 
    u[x, 0] == Sin[2 \[Pi] x], 
    u[0, t] == 0, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 1) == 2 \[Pi] E^-t}, 
   u[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 50}}];
Plot3D[{sol, E^-t Sin[2 \[Pi] x]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

It turns out that the numerical solution differs from the analytical one.

I'm confused about this, does my code have any problem or am I missing something here?

Comment: Separation of variables can't fullfill your ic and bc all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified it. Your hand solution `exp(-t)*sin(2*Pi*x)` is wrong. It does not verify the pde at all. It only verifies the BC/IC

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] - D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0
ic = u[x, 0] == Sin[2 Pi x]
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 1) == 2 Pi  Exp[-t] }
DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets check your solution

```
solNeeded = u -> Function[{x, t}, Exp[-t]*Sin[2*Pi*x]]
pde /. solNeeded
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see, it is not an identity.

most solutions for pde's come out as Fourier series and so the sum there is what one would expect. (from applying separation of variables, that is what should come out).

Mathematica's solution also agrees with Maple's

```
pde:=diff(u(x,t),t)-diff(u(x,t),x$2)=0;
ic:=u(x,0)=sin(2*Pi*x);
bc:=u(0,t)=0,D[1](u)(1,t)=2*Pi*exp(-t);
pdsolve([pde,ic,bc])
```

[image]

> does my code have any problem or am I missing something here?

Unless both Mathematica and Maple (the two most advanced CAS systems in the world) are both wrong and you are right, I would say the error is in your hand solution :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I've made a stupid mistake here :-P